# Ошибка дешифрования сообщения в RSA

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, rsa

У меня есть код, который может кодировать сообщение и сохранять их в файл **`.txt`**, так и декодировать эти данные. 
Но при декодирование возникает ошибка, как это решить?

**main.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)

    def information(self):
        self.key_crypto = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_file_ver = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_save = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.directory_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.name_key = self.lineEdit_17.text()

        self.key_task()

    def key_task(self):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

        self.key_task_crypto()

    def key_task_crypto(self):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto,
             self.key_crypto]

        directory_save_key = self.directory_key + self.name_key + ".txt"

        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))
    #####################################
    def app_key_task(self):
        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")

        print(f'directory_file = {directory_file} <----')

        with open(directory_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            print(file)

            self.number_1_decrypto = (file.readline().strip())
            self.number_2_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_3_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_4_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_5_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_6_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_7_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_8_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_9_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_10_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_11_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_12_decrypto = file.readline().strip()

            print(f'self.number_1_decrypto = {self.number_1_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_2_decrypto = {self.number_2_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_3_decrypto = {self.number_3_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_4_decrypto = {self.number_4_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_5_decrypto = {self.number_5_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_6_decrypto = {self.number_6_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_7_decrypto = {self.number_7_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_8_decrypto = {self.number_8_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_9_decrypto = {self.number_9_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_10_decrypto= {self.number_10_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_11_decrypto= {self.number_11_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_12_decrypto= {self.number_12_decrypto}')

            message = rsa.decrypt(self.number_1_decrypto, self.key_priv)
            print(message.decode('utf8'))
    #######################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**crypto.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'crypto.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 514)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab_3)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12, 11, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_19, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_17, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_14, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_15, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton, 9, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_16, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_18, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование</p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответы на задания ОГЭ с КРАТКИМ ОТВЕТОМ (проверка/настройка ключей с ответами)"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №4"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №5"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №6"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №7"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №8"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №9"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №11"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №12"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Общие настройки"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить ключ с ответами"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить данные"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя файла с ключем ответа"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Директория файлов для \n"
"проверки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывод данных в файл типа"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", ".txt"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", ".csv"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", ".docx"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория сохранения </p><p>проверенных файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дишифровать файлы"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория файлов с </p><p>ключем ответов</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ключ шифрования данных"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровка"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Настройка заданий"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">ВНИМАНИЕ! ДАННАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ПРОГРАММА НАХОДИТСЯ В БЕТА ВЕРСИИ, В НЕЙ МОГУТ ПРИСУДСТВОВАТЬ</span></p><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">НЕ РАБОЧИЕ ФУНКЦИИ. ПОЛЬЗУЯСЬ ПРОГРАММОЙ ВЫ СОГЛАШАЕТЕСЬ С ПРАВИЛАМИ ЕЁ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ. </span></p><p>(c)Copyrigth by Alexandrov Andrey </p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**:

Код ошибки:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "crypto_log.py", line 107, in app_key_task
> message = rsa.decrypt(self.number_1_decrypto, self.key_priv)
> File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 255, in decrypt
> encrypted = transform.bytes2int(crypto)
> File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\site-packages\rsa\transform.py", line 34, in bytes2int
> return int.from_bytes(raw_bytes, "big", signed=False)
> TypeError: cannot convert 'str' object to bytes

Чтобы получить данную ошибку нужно: после запуска программы открыть файл ранее созданные с зашифрованными данными (если такой отсутствует, то создать при помощи кнопки **`"Сохранить данные"`**), после чего в `cmd` появится данная ошибка.

---

**Update 2**:

Если я сохраняю данные в файл, то при следующем заходе в программу я не могу его дешифровать.

Просто, файлов с ответами должно быть множество, а открывать их должны в любое время. 
А если сохранять ключ созданный при шифрование и потом с помощью его и производить дешифровку?

Comment: Settings вам надо показать полный текст ошибки и хорошо рассказать какие действия надо выполнить чтобы получить эту ошибку.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил ошибку

Comment: @S.Nick можете помочь с вопросом?

Comment: Settings, у меня нет опыта работы с библиотекой rsa, но я попробую. чуть позже, посмотреть и что-то вам посоветовать. Только не торопите меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: @S.Nick хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я предоставил вам один из возможных вариантов как можно кодировать и декодировать эти данные. 
Вы ничего не написали подходит вам такой вариант или нет,
а лишь, в комментариях, по сути задали новый вопрос.
Этот новый вопрос о том, каков порядок создания, сохранения и выдачи публичных и секретных ключей шифрования.

Я посмотрел какие функции библиотеки ***rsa*** могут вам помочь.

Я отметил для вас изменения, которые внес в программу.

Обратите внимание:

- я добавил кнопку `btn_generate_keys`, по клику на которую
  выполнится метод `func_generate_keys`, в котором
  будут сформированы **`пара ключей`** и каждый ключ
  записывается в соответствующий файл "**key_pub.pem**" и "**key_priv.pem**". 
  Вообще-то эта операция по формированию ключей должна быть в отдельном приложении
  и выполняться отдельным уполномоченным за эту операцию лицом.
  После файл с нужным ключом передается/устанавливается определенному участнику процесса.
  Один участник должен иметь доступ к одному файлу с ключом.
- По-хорошему эту операцию по созданию ключей вам надо выполнить один раз.
- Если какой-то из ключей был скомпрометирован, то ключи надо создать новые
  и раздать участникам процесса.
  При этом вы должны понимать, что новым ключом невозможно декодировать данные,
  которые были зашифрованы старым ключом.

---

```
import os                                                                      # !!! +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa
import base64                                                                 


#from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 514)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab_3)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12, 11, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_19, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_17, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_14, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_15, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton, 9, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_16, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_18, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дешифрование файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дешифрование</p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответы на задания ОГЭ с КРАТКИМ ОТВЕТОМ (проверка/настройка ключей с ответами)"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №4"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №5"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №6"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №7"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №8"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №9"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №11"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №12"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Общие настройки"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить ключ с ответами"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить данные"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя файла с ключем ответа"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Директория файлов для \n"
"проверки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывод данных в файл типа"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", ".txt"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", ".csv"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", ".docx"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория сохранения </p><p>проверенных файлов</p></body></html>"))

        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровать файлы"))

        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория файлов с </p><p>ключем ответов</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ключ шифрования данных"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровка"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Настройка заданий"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">ВНИМАНИЕ! ДАННАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ПРОГРАММА НАХОДИТСЯ В БЕТА ВЕРСИИ, В НЕЙ МОГУТ ПРИСУДСТВОВАТЬ</span></p><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">НЕ РАБОЧИЕ ФУНКЦИИ. ПОЛЬЗУЯСЬ ПРОГРАММОЙ ВЫ СОГЛАШАЕТЕСЬ С ПРАВИЛАМИ ЕЁ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ. </span></p><p>(c)Copyrigth by Alexandrov Andrey </p></body></html>"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")
        
# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# !!! эта кнопка должна быть доступна только администратору, ответственному за генерацию ключей
        self.btn_generate_keys = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Сгенерировать ключи', self.groupBox_2)
        self.btn_generate_keys.setObjectName("btn_generate_keys")
        self.btn_generate_keys.clicked.connect(self.func_generate_keys)
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.btn_generate_keys, 10, 0, 1, 2)
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
        #print(f'\n{type(self.key_pub)} = \n{self.key_pub}')    # <class 'rsa.key.PublicKey'>
        #print(f'\n{type(self.key_priv)} = \n{self.key_priv}')  # <class 'rsa.key.PrivateKey'>

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)
        
        # добавил для тестирования
        self.lineEdit.setText('hello')
        self.lineEdit_2.setText('привет')  
        self.lineEdit_13.setText('12345')
        self.lineEdit_17.setText('1111')

    def information(self):
# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if not os.path.exists('key_pub.pem'):
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Не обнаружен "key_pub.pem"')
            return    
            
        with open('key_pub.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_pub = f.read()

        key_pub = self.key_pub.load_pkcs1(_key_pub)                             # !!! <---- key_pub
            
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
        self.key_crypto = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_file_ver = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_save = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.directory_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.name_key = self.lineEdit_17.text()

        self.key_task(key_pub)

    def key_task(self, key_pub):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text() 
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text() 
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()  
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text() 
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text() 
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text() 

        self.key_task_crypto(key_pub)

    def key_task_crypto(self, key_pub):
# !!!        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
# !!!                                                                      v^v^v^v <---- key_pub
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'),   key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), key_pub)
        self.key_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.key_crypto.encode('utf8'),      key_pub) 

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto,
             self.key_crypto]

        # k - список <class 'bytes'>. 
        # чтобы записать элемент данного списка в файл, 
        # надо указать, режим открытия файла в двоичном режиме - "wb".
        # print(f'\n{type(self.number_1_crypto)}; \n{self.number_1_crypto}\n') #
        
        directory_save_key = self.directory_key + self.name_key + ".txt"

        # открыть ф. в текст.режиме -> v
        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            # --------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <---- это строка        
            f.write("\n".join(base64.b64encode(item).decode('utf8') for item in k))

        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 'Успех', 
            'Данные сохранены.'
        )
 
    def app_key_task(self):
# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

        if not os.path.exists('key_priv.pem'):
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Не обнаружен "key_priv.pem"')
            return
            
        with open('key_priv.pem', "rb") as f:
            _key_priv = f.read()

        key_priv = self.key_priv.load_pkcs1(_key_priv)
        
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          
        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")
        if not directory_file:
            return
            
        # открыть файл ----------> v  <---- в текстовом режиме 
        with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
# !!! ---   decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), self.key_priv)
            decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), key_priv)            # !!! +++ 
            print(decrypted.decode('utf8'))
        print(f'\n -=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- \n') #  

# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def func_generate_keys(self):
    
# !!! +++  тут надо сделать запрос-уточнение о серьезности намерений выполнить эти действия # !!! +++ 

        save_key_pub = self.key_pub.save_pkcs1()
        with open('key_pub.pem', "wb") as f:
            f.write(save_key_pub)
            
        save_key_priv = self.key_priv.save_pkcs1()            
        with open('key_priv.pem', "wb") as f:
            f.write(save_key_priv)            

        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            'Успех', 
            
            '<p style="color: #02475E; text-align: center;"> Файлы ключей <br>'
            '"key_pub.pem" и "key_priv.pem" <br>сформированы. <br>'
            'Передайте нужные ключи участникам соревнований :)<\p>'
        )            


qss = '''
QMessageBox {
    background: #F8F5F1;
}
QMessageBox QLabel {
    color: #02475E;
    text-align: center;    
    font-size: 15px;
}
QMessageBox::title {
    background-color: #00f;
    text-align: center;
    height: 12px;    
    color: white;
}
'''

# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                                                    # +++  
    
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это то, что нужно, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Settings пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Я прокомментировал свои изменение и добавления по тексту программы.

Обратите внимание, что кодировать сообщение и сохранять их в файл, так и декодировать их из файла вы можете в рамках одного сеанса приложения. 
Так как при каждом новом запуске приложения вы создаете новые ключи:

```
(self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
```

---

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa
import base64                                                                  # !!! +++


#from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 514)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab_3)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12, 11, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_19, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_17, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_14, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_15, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton, 9, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_16, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_18, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование</p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответы на задания ОГЭ с КРАТКИМ ОТВЕТОМ (проверка/настройка ключей с ответами)"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №4"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №5"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №6"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №7"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №8"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №9"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №11"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №12"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Общие настройки"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить ключ с ответами"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить данные"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя файла с ключем ответа"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Директория файлов для \n"
"проверки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывод данных в файл типа"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", ".txt"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", ".csv"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", ".docx"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория сохранения </p><p>проверенных файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дишифровать файлы"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория файлов с </p><p>ключем ответов</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ключ шифрования данных"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровка"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Настройка заданий"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">ВНИМАНИЕ! ДАННАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ПРОГРАММА НАХОДИТСЯ В БЕТА ВЕРСИИ, В НЕЙ МОГУТ ПРИСУДСТВОВАТЬ</span></p><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">НЕ РАБОЧИЕ ФУНКЦИИ. ПОЛЬЗУЯСЬ ПРОГРАММОЙ ВЫ СОГЛАШАЕТЕСЬ С ПРАВИЛАМИ ЕЁ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ. </span></p><p>(c)Copyrigth by Alexandrov Andrey </p></body></html>"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
#        print(f'{type(self.key_pub)} = {self.key_pub}') #
#        print(f'{type(self.key_priv)} = {self.key_priv}') #

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)
        
# +++ добавил для тестирования
        self.lineEdit.setText('hello')
        self.lineEdit_2.setText('привет')  
        self.lineEdit_13.setText('12345')
        self.lineEdit_17.setText('1111')

    def information(self):
        self.key_crypto = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_file_ver = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_save = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.directory_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.name_key = self.lineEdit_17.text()

        self.key_task()

    def key_task(self):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text() 
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text() 
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()  
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text() 
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text() 
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text() 

        self.key_task_crypto()

    def key_task_crypto(self):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
# !!! +++
        self.key_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.key_crypto.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)       # !!! +++

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto,
             self.key_crypto]

# k - список <class 'bytes'>. 
# чтобы записать элемент данного списка в файл, 
# надо указать, режим открытия файла в двоичном режиме - "wb".
        print(f'\n{type(self.number_1_crypto)}; \n{self.number_1_crypto}\n') #
        
        directory_save_key = self.directory_key + self.name_key + ".txt"

# открыть файл в текстовом режиме ---> v
        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
# --------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <---- это строка        
            f.write("\n".join(base64.b64encode(item).decode('utf8') for item in k))
 
 
    def app_key_task(self):
        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")
        if not directory_file:
            return
            
# открыть файл ------------------> v  <---- в текстовом режиме 
        with open(directory_file, "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        
        for line in lines:
            decrypted = rsa.decrypt(base64.b64decode(line.strip()), self.key_priv)
            print(decrypted.decode('utf8'))

        print(f'\n -=-=--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- \n') #  
            
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то есть если я сохраню данные в файл, то при следующем заходе в программу я не смогу его дешифровать?

Comment: Просто, файлов с ответами должно быть множество, а открывать их должны в любое время. А если сохранять ключ созданный при шифрование, и потом с помощью его и производить дешифровку?

Comment: @Settings, я же вам писал, что у меня нет опыта работы с библиотекой rsa 
и поэтому я не знаю как правильно работать с ключами и как сохранять их. 
Но это уже другой вопрос, я лишь констатирую факт, 
что вы при каждом входе создаете новые ключи.

Comment: понял, спасибо за помощь)